How to rotate an object to look at your cursor but only on Y-axis?
How to rotate an object alsongside your cursor?
I use
void Update()
{
    Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (plane.Raycast(ray, out float distance))
    {
        Vector3 targetposition = ray.GetPoint(distance);
       transform.LookAt(targetposition);
    }
}


I removed a bit of clutter from your question ... repeating each line of code is a bit redundant as we can see what you are doing ;) ... Please rather extend on what exactly doesn't behave the way you expected .. what happens instead? .. From the code I would guess it should do what you want and only rotate around the Y axis ...

This question is similar to: how do i make an enemy look at a player only on the x axis in unity. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The equivalent to:
this.transform.LookAt(target);

but constrained to rotation on only y-axis is:
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward: Vector3.up,
                                              upwards: target.position - this.transform.position);
Quaternion offset = Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 180);
this.transform.rotation = rotation * offset;

